# How make Wings in SVG move with css3 animations

Tags: html, css, svg

i have this wings made in SVG, and i want apply the fly effect in the .wing class, but if i try, the animation will not occurs correctly.

Animation in the SVG:

```css
svg {
  -webkit-animation:fly 1s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fly {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="183px" height="159.5px" viewBox="0 0 183 159.5" enable-background="new 0 0 183 159.5" xml:space="preserve">
<g class="wings">
 <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M30.835,81.005c-2.062,0.463-4.049,0.568-6.003,0.018
  c-0.752-0.213-1.551-0.514-2.136-1.006c-1.08-0.91-1.619-2.482,0.424-3.371c0.217-0.096,0.459-0.129,0.681-0.217
  c3.698-1.48,7.59-2.438,11.198-4.164c1.65-0.79,3.332-1.513,4.958-2.247c0.093-2.03,1.316-2.938,2.914-3.51
  c0.3-0.108,0.612-0.187,0.923-0.256c2.5-0.555,4.93-1.344,7.224-2.469c2.792-1.37,5.543-2.83,8.268-4.329
  c2.241-1.233,4.562-1.794,7.129-1.482c2.697,0.327,4.362,2.809,3.448,5.334c-0.188,0.523-0.463,1.017-0.707,1.519
  c-2.003,4.092-3.637,8.322-4.689,12.76c-0.237,1-0.861,1.428-1.783,1.684c-1.069,0.297-2.036-0.125-3.095-0.34
  c-0.453,0.303-0.95,0.566-1.363,0.926c-1.442,1.26-2.899,2.504-4.265,3.842c-1.447,1.418-3.165,1.896-5.059,1.482
  c-0.96-0.211-1.825-0.854-2.907-1.387c-2.312,0.957-4.757,1.131-6.948-0.859C35.893,83.944,33.045,83.702,30.835,81.005z
   M52.091,74.009c2.577-0.914,4.953-2.223,6.999-4.054c1.069-0.956,2.034-2.026,3.072-3.017c0.501-0.479,0.817-0.397,1.618,0.354
  c-2.516,3.723-6.121,6.11-10.096,8.065c1.243,1.246,2.181,1.549,3.383,0.82c1.077-0.652,2.05-1.506,2.98-2.365
  c0.816-0.754,1.489-1.662,2.275-2.453c0.172-0.172,0.746-0.26,0.812-0.163c0.206,0.297,0.439,0.776,0.33,1.049
  c-0.232,0.574-0.633,1.102-1.042,1.582c-0.926,1.082-1.897,2.123-2.853,3.184c0.903,0.711,0.898,0.725,2.389,0.834
  c0.196-0.365,0.489-0.75,0.623-1.184c1.394-4.514,3.022-8.919,5.588-12.927c0.253-0.395,0.393-0.875,0.52-1.334
  c0.4-1.457-0.154-2.567-1.645-2.927c-1.553-0.376-3.172-0.5-4.696,0.159c-1.682,0.727-3.391,1.437-4.965,2.363
  c-2.829,1.664-5.775,3.057-8.81,4.279c-1.258,0.506-2.537,0.966-3.829,1.377c-0.996,0.317-1.942,0.675-2.69,1.473
  c0.34,1.451,1.42,1.95,2.647,1.993c2.126,0.075,4.197-0.076,6.292-0.812c3.508-1.232,6.669-2.973,9.573-5.248
  c0.18-0.141,0.42-0.226,0.646-0.278c0.135-0.031,0.372,0.005,0.43,0.096c0.113,0.181,0.257,0.528,0.177,0.618
  c-0.58,0.647-1.127,1.382-1.844,1.839c-2.554,1.626-5.103,3.295-8.075,4.096c-1.075,0.29-1.998,0.863-3.045,1.271
  C50.092,74.313,50.572,74.548,52.091,74.009z M24.532,77.942c-0.198,0.07-0.339,0.301-0.634,0.574
  c0.324,0.354,0.562,0.818,0.931,0.977c1.34,0.574,2.798,0.887,4.212,0.588c2.166-0.459,4.382-0.699,6.444-1.674
  c3.159-1.494,6.402-2.809,9.6-4.221c0.646-0.285,1.247-0.664,1.806-0.965c0.128-0.588-0.289-0.693-0.532-0.672
  c-1.886,0.158-3.631-0.211-5.238-1.39C35.735,73.864,30.151,75.948,24.532,77.942z M47.34,74.364
  c-1.532,0.715-3.106,1.449-4.68,2.186c-1.578,0.738-3.161,1.465-4.729,2.221c-1.532,0.74-3.364,0.848-4.747,2.141
  c0.633,0.898,1.437,1.084,2.329,1.137c1.309,0.078,2.529-0.336,3.71-0.764c2.313-0.84,4.556-1.859,6.632-3.211
  c0.53-0.344,1.108-0.611,1.654-0.932c0.671-0.395,1.332-0.805,2.188-1.324C48.721,75.216,48.057,74.806,47.34,74.364z
   M51.208,76.788c-1.247,0.695-2.475,1.43-3.733,2.102c-1.746,0.934-3.518,1.82-5.273,2.736c-0.336,0.176-0.652,0.387-0.938,0.559
  c0.005,0.697,0.514,0.752,0.826,0.73c0.854-0.061,1.747-0.115,2.538-0.408c2.134-0.791,6.32-3.355,8.476-5.064
  C52.546,76.626,51.975,76.36,51.208,76.788z M54.158,78.794c-1.699,1.184-3.457,2.279-5.185,3.418
  c-0.257,0.17-0.484,0.379-0.872,0.689c0.466,0.33,0.796,0.734,1.189,0.807c0.885,0.166,1.759-0.039,2.471-0.631
  c1.951-1.625,3.884-3.271,6.235-5.258C56.296,77.937,55.185,78.081,54.158,78.794z"/>
 <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FEF4F3" d="M48.856,72.7c1.235,1.613,1.716,1.848,3.234,1.309
  c2.577-0.914,4.953-2.223,6.999-4.054c1.069-0.956,2.034-2.026,3.072-3.017c0.501-0.479,0.817-0.397,1.618,0.354
  c-2.516,3.723-6.121,6.11-10.096,8.065c1.243,1.246,2.181,1.549,3.383,0.82c1.077-0.652,2.05-1.506,2.98-2.365
  c0.816-0.754,1.489-1.662,2.275-2.453c0.172-0.172,0.746-0.26,0.812-0.163c0.206,0.297,0.439,0.776,0.33,1.049
  c-0.232,0.574-0.633,1.102-1.042,1.582c-0.926,1.082-1.897,2.123-2.853,3.184c0.903,0.711,0.898,0.725,2.389,0.834
  c0.196-0.365,0.489-0.75,0.623-1.184c1.394-4.514,3.022-8.919,5.588-12.927c0.253-0.395,0.393-0.875,0.52-1.334
  c0.4-1.457-0.154-2.567-1.645-2.927c-1.553-0.376-3.172-0.5-4.696,0.159c-1.682,0.727-3.391,1.437-4.965,2.363
  c-2.829,1.664-5.775,3.057-8.81,4.279c-1.258,0.506-2.537,0.966-3.829,1.377c-0.996,0.317-1.942,0.675-2.69,1.473
  c0.34,1.451,1.42,1.95,2.647,1.993c2.126,0.075,4.197-0.076,6.292-0.812c3.508-1.232,6.669-2.973,9.573-5.248
  c0.18-0.141,0.42-0.226,0.646-0.278c0.135-0.031,0.372,0.005,0.43,0.096c0.113,0.181,0.257,0.528,0.177,0.618
  c-0.58,0.647-1.127,1.382-1.844,1.839c-2.554,1.626-5.103,3.295-8.075,4.096C50.826,71.719,49.903,72.292,48.856,72.7z"/>
 <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FEF4F3" d="M41.12,71.16c-5.385,2.705-10.969,4.789-16.588,6.783
  c-0.198,0.07-0.339,0.301-0.634,0.574c0.324,0.354,0.562,0.818,0.931,0.977c1.34,0.574,2.798,0.887,4.212,0.588
  c2.166-0.459,4.382-0.699,6.444-1.674c3.159-1.494,6.402-2.809,9.6-4.221c0.646-0.285,1.247-0.664,1.806-0.965
  c0.128-0.588-0.289-0.693-0.532-0.672C44.473,72.708,42.728,72.339,41.12,71.16z"/>
 <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FEF4F3" d="M49.697,75.817c-0.977-0.602-1.641-1.012-2.357-1.453
  c-1.532,0.715-3.106,1.449-4.68,2.186c-1.578,0.738-3.161,1.465-4.729,2.221c-1.532,0.74-3.364,0.848-4.747,2.141
  c0.633,0.898,1.437,1.084,2.329,1.137c1.309,0.078,2.529-0.336,3.71-0.764c2.313-0.84,4.556-1.859,6.632-3.211
  c0.53-0.344,1.108-0.611,1.654-0.932C48.18,76.747,48.841,76.337,49.697,75.817z"/>
 <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FEF4F3" d="M53.104,77.442c-0.558-0.816-1.129-1.082-1.896-0.654
  c-1.247,0.695-2.475,1.43-3.733,2.102c-1.746,0.934-3.518,1.82-5.273,2.736c-0.336,0.176-0.652,0.387-0.938,0.559
  c0.005,0.697,0.514,0.752,0.826,0.73c0.854-0.061,1.747-0.115,2.538-0.408C46.762,81.716,50.948,79.151,53.104,77.442z"/>
 <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FEF4F3" d="M57.997,77.819c-1.701,0.117-2.812,0.262-3.839,0.975
  c-1.699,1.184-3.457,2.279-5.185,3.418c-0.257,0.17-0.484,0.379-0.872,0.689c0.466,0.33,0.796,0.734,1.189,0.807
  c0.885,0.166,1.759-0.039,2.471-0.631C53.713,81.452,55.646,79.806,57.997,77.819z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Animation in the .wings:

```css
.wings {
  -webkit-animation:fly 1s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fly {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="183px" height="159.5px" viewBox="0 0 183 159.5" enable-background="new 0 0 183 159.5" xml:space="preserve">
<g class="wings">
 <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M30.835,81.005c-2.062,0.463-4.049,0.568-6.003,0.018
  c-0.752-0.213-1.551-0.514-2.136-1.006c-1.08-0.91-1.619-2.482,0.424-3.371c0.217-0.096,0.459-0.129,0.681-0.217
  c3.698-1.48,7.59-2.438,11.198-4.164c1.65-0.79,3.332-1.513,4.958-2.247c0.093-2.03,1.316-2.938,2.914-3.51
  c0.3-0.108,0.612-0.187,0.923-0.256c2.5-0.555,4.93-1.344,7.224-2.469c2.792-1.37,5.543-2.83,8.268-4.329
  c2.241-1.233,4.562-1.794,7.129-1.482c2.697,0.327,4.362,2.809,3.448,5.334c-0.188,0.523-0.463,1.017-0.707,1.519
  c-2.003,4.092-3.637,8.322-4.689,12.76c-0.237,1-0.861,1.428-1.783,1.684c-1.069,0.297-2.036-0.125-3.095-0.34
  c-0.453,0.303-0.95,0.566-1.363,0.926c-1.442,1.26-2.899,2.504-4.265,3.842c-1.447,1.418-3.165,1.896-5.059,1.482
  c-0.96-0.211-1.825-0.854-2.907-1.387c-2.312,0.957-4.757,1.131-6.948-0.859C35.893,83.944,33.045,83.702,30.835,81.005z
   M52.091,74.009c2.577-0.914,4.953-2.223,6.999-4.054c1.069-0.956,2.034-2.026,3.072-3.017c0.501-0.479,0.817-0.397,1.618,0.354
  c-2.516,3.723-6.121,6.11-10.096,8.065c1.243,1.246,2.181,1.549,3.383,0.82c1.077-0.652,2.05-1.506,2.98-2.365
  c0.816-0.754,1.489-1.662,2.275-2.453c0.172-0.172,0.746-0.26,0.812-0.163c0.206,0.297,0.439,0.776,0.33,1.049
  c-0.232,0.574-0.633,1.102-1.042,1.582c-0.926,1.082-1.897,2.123-2.853,3.184c0.903,0.711,0.898,0.725,2.389,0.834
  c0.196-0.365,0.489-0.75,0.623-1.184c1.394-4.514,3.022-8.919,5.588-12.927c0.253-0.395,0.393-0.875,0.52-1.334
  c0.4-1.457-0.154-2.567-1.645-2.927c-1.553-0.376-3.172-0.5-4.696,0.159c-1.682,0.727-3.391,1.437-4.965,2.363
  c-2.829,1.664-5.775,3.057-8.81,4.279c-1.258,0.506-2.537,0.966-3.829,1.377c-0.996,0.317-1.942,0.675-2.69,1.473
  c0.34,1.451,1.42,1.95,2.647,1.993c2.126,0.075,4.197-0.076,6.292-0.812c3.508-1.232,6.669-2.973,9.573-5.248
  c0.18-0.141,0.42-0.226,0.646-0.278c0.135-0.031,0.372,0.005,0.43,0.096c0.113,0.181,0.257,0.528,0.177,0.618
  c-0.58,0.647-1.127,1.382-1.844,1.839c-2.554,1.626-5.103,3.295-8.075,4.096c-1.075,0.29-1.998,0.863-3.045,1.271
  C50.092,74.313,50.572,74.548,52.091,74.009z M24.532,77.942c-0.198,0.07-0.339,0.301-0.634,0.574
  c0.324,0.354,0.562,0.818,0.931,0.977c1.34,0.574,2.798,0.887,4.212,0.588c2.166-0.459,4.382-0.699,6.444-1.674
  c3.159-1.494,6.402-2.809,9.6-4.221c0.646-0.285,1.247-0.664,1.806-0.965c0.128-0.588-0.289-0.693-0.532-0.672
  c-1.886,0.158-3.631-0.211-5.238-1.39C35.735,73.864,30.151,75.948,24.532,77.942z M47.34,74.364
  c-1.532,0.715-3.106,1.449-4.68,2.186c-1.578,0.738-3.161,1.465-4.729,2.221c-1.532,0.74-3.364,0.848-4.747,2.141
  c0.633,0.898,1.437,1.084,2.329,1.137c1.309,0.078,2.529-0.336,3.71-0.764c2.313-0.84,4.556-1.859,6.632-3.211
  c0.53-0.344,1.108-0.611,1.654-0.932c0.671-0.395,1.332-0.805,2.188-1.324C48.721,75.216,48.057,74.806,47.34,74.364z
   M51.208,76.788c-1.247,0.695-2.475,1.43-3.733,2.102c-1.746,0.934-3.518,1.82-5.273,2.736c-0.336,0.176-0.652,0.387-0.938,0.559
  c0.005,0.697,0.514,0.752,0.826,0.73c0.854-0.061,1.747-0.115,2.538-0.408c2.134-0.791,6.32-3.355,8.476-5.064
  C52.546,76.626,51.975,76.36,51.208,76.788z M54.158,78.794c-1.699,1.184-3.457,2.279-5.185,3.418
  c-0.257,0.17-0.484,0.379-0.872,0.689c0.466,0.33,0.796,0.734,1.189,0.807c0.885,0.166,1.759-0.039,2.471-0.631
  c1.951-1.625,3.884-3.271,6.235-5.258C56.296,77.937,55.185,78.081,54.158,78.794z"/>
 <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FEF4F3" d="M48.856,72.7c1.235,1.613,1.716,1.848,3.234,1.309
  c2.577-0.914,4.953-2.223,6.999-4.054c1.069-0.956,2.034-2.026,3.072-3.017c0.501-0.479,0.817-0.397,1.618,0.354
  c-2.516,3.723-6.121,6.11-10.096,8.065c1.243,1.246,2.181,1.549,3.383,0.82c1.077-0.652,2.05-1.506,2.98-2.365
  c0.816-0.754,1.489-1.662,2.275-2.453c0.172-0.172,0.746-0.26,0.812-0.163c0.206,0.297,0.439,0.776,0.33,1.049
  c-0.232,0.574-0.633,1.102-1.042,1.582c-0.926,1.082-1.897,2.123-2.853,3.184c0.903,0.711,0.898,0.725,2.389,0.834
  c0.196-0.365,0.489-0.75,0.623-1.184c1.394-4.514,3.022-8.919,5.588-12.927c0.253-0.395,0.393-0.875,0.52-1.334
  c0.4-1.457-0.154-2.567-1.645-2.927c-1.553-0.376-3.172-0.5-4.696,0.159c-1.682,0.727-3.391,1.437-4.965,2.363
  c-2.829,1.664-5.775,3.057-8.81,4.279c-1.258,0.506-2.537,0.966-3.829,1.377c-0.996,0.317-1.942,0.675-2.69,1.473
  c0.34,1.451,1.42,1.95,2.647,1.993c2.126,0.075,4.197-0.076,6.292-0.812c3.508-1.232,6.669-2.973,9.573-5.248
  c0.18-0.141,0.42-0.226,0.646-0.278c0.135-0.031,0.372,0.005,0.43,0.096c0.113,0.181,0.257,0.528,0.177,0.618
  c-0.58,0.647-1.127,1.382-1.844,1.839c-2.554,1.626-5.103,3.295-8.075,4.096C50.826,71.719,49.903,72.292,48.856,72.7z"/>
 <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FEF4F3" d="M41.12,71.16c-5.385,2.705-10.969,4.789-16.588,6.783
  c-0.198,0.07-0.339,0.301-0.634,0.574c0.324,0.354,0.562,0.818,0.931,0.977c1.34,0.574,2.798,0.887,4.212,0.588
  c2.166-0.459,4.382-0.699,6.444-1.674c3.159-1.494,6.402-2.809,9.6-4.221c0.646-0.285,1.247-0.664,1.806-0.965
  c0.128-0.588-0.289-0.693-0.532-0.672C44.473,72.708,42.728,72.339,41.12,71.16z"/>
 <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FEF4F3" d="M49.697,75.817c-0.977-0.602-1.641-1.012-2.357-1.453
  c-1.532,0.715-3.106,1.449-4.68,2.186c-1.578,0.738-3.161,1.465-4.729,2.221c-1.532,0.74-3.364,0.848-4.747,2.141
  c0.633,0.898,1.437,1.084,2.329,1.137c1.309,0.078,2.529-0.336,3.71-0.764c2.313-0.84,4.556-1.859,6.632-3.211
  c0.53-0.344,1.108-0.611,1.654-0.932C48.18,76.747,48.841,76.337,49.697,75.817z"/>
 <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FEF4F3" d="M53.104,77.442c-0.558-0.816-1.129-1.082-1.896-0.654
  c-1.247,0.695-2.475,1.43-3.733,2.102c-1.746,0.934-3.518,1.82-5.273,2.736c-0.336,0.176-0.652,0.387-0.938,0.559
  c0.005,0.697,0.514,0.752,0.826,0.73c0.854-0.061,1.747-0.115,2.538-0.408C46.762,81.716,50.948,79.151,53.104,77.442z"/>
 <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FEF4F3" d="M57.997,77.819c-1.701,0.117-2.812,0.262-3.839,0.975
  c-1.699,1.184-3.457,2.279-5.185,3.418c-0.257,0.17-0.484,0.379-0.872,0.689c0.466,0.33,0.796,0.734,1.189,0.807
  c0.885,0.166,1.759-0.039,2.471-0.631C53.713,81.452,55.646,79.806,57.997,77.819z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Why this is happening? How the animation can change like this, and how fix?

Ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the SVG coordinate system is not the same as the CSS box model and there are a series of article on [Understanding SVG Coordinate Systems and Transformations](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/) (with links at the top to her other articles regarding rotations and animations) that can take you through some of the things to be considered when applying CSS directly to the SVG.

It looks very much like the .wings CSS is rotating the wing around the origin of (0,0) at the top left of the image (I added a red border to the SVG element (in CSS) so you could see what's happening in both cases)

[image]

but the .svg is applying the transform to the whole viewbox of the SVG and its doing it around the very centre (midpoints) of that viewbox.

[image].

So you're going to need to apply a transform to allow for the shift back of the origin.

So you can either explicitly put the origin and animation of the wing into the SVG file itself on each of the "movable" items or load more than one SVG file and apply them whole and animate multiple moving parts with separate files or work out the transform-origin: you need to apply in the CSS to achieve the same thing.